# find longest shortest attribute in a list of objects

Tags: python, min

If you have a list of objects each with a specific attribute which contains an array of random length. Is there an easy way to find the length of the shortest attribute?

I know if it was a list of strings I could use the following.

```
min(alist, key=len)
```

Is there a way I can edit this to search by an object attribute within the list?

Comment: Please provide more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do, you can access it with a `lambda`:

```
lowest = min(alist, key=lambda o: len(o.attr_name))
```

that will sort the items by that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorted` as follows:

```
new_list = min(your_list, key=lambda x: len(x.nums))
```

#### Example

```
from random import randint

class thing():
    def __init__(self):
        self.nums = [0]*randint(5,15)

obj_list = [thing() for _ in range(10)]

new_list = min(obj_list, key=lambda x: len(x.nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as a alternative to lambda solution:

```
min((len(obj.attr) for obj in obj_list))
```